# Font Size of acroFields of pdf is coming 0 using iText

Tags: itext

I am using this code to get font size of AcroField of PDF.

But font size for a AcroField named "first name last name" is coming out to be 0 (Although its actual font is 32.3).

The font size of other fields are coming accurate.Kindly help me to get exact font size.

My code is...

```
 final AcroFields.Item item = acroFields.getFieldItem(fieldName);

 ArrayList list =null;
 if(item!=null)
    list = item.merged;
    if (list != null) 
    {
    for (final Iterator it1 = list.iterator(); it1.hasNext();) 
    {
        final PdfDictionary itemDict = (PdfDictionary) it1.next();
        final PdfObject da = itemDict.get(PdfName.DA);
        System.out.println(da.toString()); //font size is printing out to be 0;
    }
 }
```

New Code is

```
       import java.util.ArrayList;
       import java.util.Iterator;
       import java.util.Map;
       import java.util.Set;
       import com.lowagie.text.pdf.AcroFields;
       import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PRStream;
       import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDictionary;
       import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfEncodings;
       import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfName;
       import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader;
       import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStamper;
       import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStream;

     public class MyTest {      

        public static void main(String[] args) {

    String pdfName = "Crunch-Business_card_NRW_edits.pdf";      

    PdfStamper stamper = null;
    FileOutputStream fout = null;   
    try{
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfName);
        fout = new FileOutputStream("output.pdf");
        stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fout); 

        AcroFields acroFields = stamper.getAcroFields();
        Map fieldMap = acroFields.getFields(); 
        Set keys = fieldMap.keySet();

        for (Iterator it = keys.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
        {
            String fieldName  = (String) it.next(); 
            acroFields.setField(fieldName,acroFields.getField(fieldName));

            final AcroFields.Item item = acroFields.getFieldItem(fieldName);
            final ArrayList list = item.merged;
            if (list != null) {
                for (final Iterator it1 = list.iterator(); it1.hasNext();) {
                    final PdfDictionary itemDict = (PdfDictionary) it1.next();

                    PdfDictionary appearanceDict = itemDict.getAsDict(PdfName.AP);
                    PdfStream normalAppearance = appearanceDict.getAsStream(PdfName.N);

                    System.out.println("normalAppearance======"+normalAppearance);// normalAppearance is coming null.
                    byte[] streamBytes = PdfReader.getStreamBytes((PRStream) normalAppearance);
                    System.out.println(PdfEncodings.convertToString(streamBytes, null));
                }
            }

        }                       
        stamper.setFreeTextFlattening(false);
        stamper.setFormFlattening(false);
        stamper.close(); 
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

The link for the PDF is http://www.mediafire.com/view/?tpjql3ipn3xqpbo.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your link requires some login.

Comment: I have updated my previous link.The link is http://www.mediafire.com/view/?tpjql3ipn3xqpbo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*In essence:*

0 means 'auto-size': You have to calculate a size which fits.

*In detail:*

Let's look at the field definition in the document:

```
52 0 obj
<<
    /Ff 41943042
    /F 4
    /Type/Annot
    /RV(<?xml version="1.0"?>
        <body xfa:APIVersion="Acroform:2.7.0.0" xfa:spec="2.1"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
              xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/">
            <p dir="ltr"
               style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;text-valign:middle;
                      font-family:'Alternate Gothic LT';font-size:30pt;
                      color:#ffffff">first name last name</p>
        </body>)
    /Subtype/Widget
    /DV(first name last name)
    /T(name)
    /V(first name last name)
    /DS(font: 'Alternate Gothic LT',sans-serif 12.0pt; text-align:left; color:#FFFFFF )
    /AP<</N 7 0 R>>
    /P 21 0 R
    /MK<<>>
    /FT/Tx
    /Rect[36.8297 87.7383 250.89 129.353]
    /DA(/AlternateGothicLT-No3 0 Tf 1 1 1 rg)
>>
endobj
```

And at the content of the appearance stream in 7 0:

```
q Q /Tx
BMC
q
0 0 214.06 41.61 re W n
q
BT
1 0 0 1 2 7.14 Tm
/AlternateGothicLT-No3 32.31 Tf
1 1 1 rg
(first name last name)Tj
0 g
ET
Q
Q
EMC
```

So just like you read via iText, the **DA** (default appearance) string sets the font at size 0.

According to the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf), page 435, this means:

> The default appearance string (DA) contains any graphics state or text state operators needed to establish the graphics state parameters, such as text size and colour, for displaying the field’s variable text. Only operators that are allowed within text objects shall occur in this string (see Figure 9). At a minimum, the string shall include a Tf (text font) operator along with its two operands, font and size. The specified font value shall match a resource name in the Font entry of the default resource dictionary (referenced from the DR entry of the interactive form dictionary; see Table 218). A zero value for size means that the font shall be auto-sized: its size shall be computed as a function of the height of the annotation rectangle.

**So the size has to be calculated to fill the space available but not more.**

In the appearance stream you see that the last creator of an appearance considered 32.31 pt to do the job.

**EDIT**

You can extract the bytes of the normal appearance stream like this:

```
PdfDictionary appearanceDict = itemDict.getAsDict(PdfName.AP);
PdfStream normalAppearance = appearanceDict.getAsStream(PdfName.N);
byte[] streamBytes = PdfReader.getStreamBytes((PRStream) normalAppearance);
System.out.println(PdfEncodings.convertToString(streamBytes, null));
```

Comment: Thanks for your  reply...But can you elaborate how can i get exact size??

Comment: The citation from the specification indicates that you should take the height of the form field annotation and fit your font into it. The fields items you already use provide you with size information, in your case 87,7383 up to 129,353, a difference of more than 41,6. Now you have to subtract a bit to have the writing not collide with the border. The former appearances creater used 32.31. You can get that number from the appearance stream.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your immediate reply.Sir I am novice to itext.I have tried to get field definition of document.I am not able to get "the content of the appearance stream in 7 0". However I got the "field definition in the document:" by this code.


     
   
   Kindly help me to get the appearance stream.

Comment: My code for getting field definition in the documentis---
final AcroFields.Item item = acroFields.getFieldItem(fieldName);
final ArrayList list = item.merged;
if (list != null)
 { 
for (final Iterator it1 = list.iterator(); 
it1.hasNext();) 
 {
   final PdfDictionary itemDict = (PdfDictionary) it1.next();       Set asd = itemDict.getKeys();
  Iterator iter = asd.iterator();
  while(iter.hasNext())
 { PdfName key = (PdfName)iter.next();
 PdfDictionary itemDict1 = (PdfDictionary)itemDict.get(PdfName.AP);
 System.out.println("\n\nPdfDictionary==========="+key+" "+itemDict.get(key));

Comment: Set asd1 = itemDict1.getKeys();
Iterator iter1 = asd1.iterator();
while(iter1.hasNext())
{
PdfName key1 = (PdfName)iter1.next();
System.out.println("\n\nPdfDictionary==========="+key1+" "+itemDict1.get(key1)); 
}}}}

Comment: I added code to extract the appearance stream bytes using the `itemDict` available in the code in your question.

Comment: Hi @mkl thanks a lot for your code.I have tried your code.But normalAppearance (PdfStream normalAppearance = appearanceDict.getAsStream(PdfName.N);) is coming out to be null.I have updated my code (added new code) in my question.I am using iText 2.0.6.Kindly help me to figure out my mistake.

Comment: I have tested the code, it worked with your PDF. **But** I did use a **current** iText version, **not** such an **ancient** one. If you for some reason cannot upgrade to iText 5.x, you at least should use 2.1.7 or the official unofficial release 4.2.0.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I have got my mistake.I removed the line "acroFields.setField(fieldName,acroFields.getField(fieldName));" from code and got the result.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried solution provided by @mkl and got the expected result.
This is the solution as explained by @mkl.

```
PdfDictionary appearanceDict = itemDict.getAsDict(PdfName.AP);
PdfStream normalAppearance = appearanceDict.getAsStream(PdfName.N);
byte[] streamBytes = PdfReader.getStreamBytes((PRStream) normalAppearance);
System.out.println(PdfEncodings.convertToString(streamBytes, null));
```